# SharePoint 2010 Analytics Report

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, analytics

I am kind of new to analytics and not sure how many are still working on this feature of SharePoint 2010.

Before I being I would like to let you know that I am referring to below link in order to navigate and view analytics report.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ecm/2010/03/20/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010/

When I navigate to my site's site settings page and click on "Site Web Analytics reports" link under "Site Actions" I do not see all the options which are being shown in the above article. I only see two options "Previous Day" and "Previous 30 Days". Missing options are "More", "Export to Spreadsheet". What I would like to do is export the site level report and generate custom reports.

[image]

But When I do the same steps in Central Admin site I see all the options there. Also when I am on Central Admin Site I can see the report only for Web Application level and not on site collection or site level.

**EDIT on 15-Mar**

In central admin I am navigating to "Monitoring" -> "View Web Analytics reports" which redirects me to Web Application Selection screen. Upon selection of web application, I am being redirected to "_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx" page. Is it possible that I can enable similar features(Preceding 90 Days, Preceding 180 Days, Preceding 365 Days, Custom Dates) site level?

[image]

So here are my questions,

1. Is there a way I can enable these options on site level?
2. Are these features not available on site level?

Answer (score 0):

These options are available in Site Collection Web Analytics reports and Site Web Analytics reports.

Check if you have configured Web Analytics service application.

[How to configure Web Analytics service application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382(v=office.14).aspx)

[Detail steps about How to configure Web Analytics service application with screenshots](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/SharePoint-2010-Site-Collection-and-Sites-Health-Analyzer-through-SharePoint-Web-Analytics-Services)